# Mac OSX Lion app with maximum width only in fullscreen mode

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, osx-lion, fullscreen

I'm looking for a way to have an app in Lion expand to a maximum width and 100% height in fullscreen mode (like the Messages beta app) but enable a user to scale it to all sizes when not in fullscreen mode.

Is this possible using only Interface Builder, or should I code it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to code this since Interface Builder doesn't give you any size specifics for how the application behaves in full-screen.

By using the [NSWindowDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) methods you should be able to tell the window how to behave when it enters and exits fullscreen

Once you have entered or exited fullscreen mode you can set the max size of your window using setMaxSize: on your window outlet. The delegate methods – windowWillEnterFullScreen: and – windowWillExitFullScreen: should be the most useful